# How to extract data from an XML file using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

How to extract data from this XML with PL/SQL?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE BPS SYSTEM "bpml.dtd">
<BPS Created="2012-04-24 11:40:41">
<Machine SerialNumber="" Site="" SoftwareRelease="MAP_248204031" VersionInfo="" Name="" Type="BPS200">
  <ParameterSection Number="6" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:23:01" EndTime="1970-01-01 00:00:00">
    <HeadercardUnit HeaderCardID="1706539" DepositID="01706539" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:39:57" MilliSec="0" EndTime="2012-04-24 11:40:40" Rejects="NO">
      <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Fit" Output="Stacked" Number="192"></Counter>
      <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Unfit" Output="Stacked" Number="7"></Counter>
    </HeadercardUnit>
  </ParameterSection>
</Machine>
</BPS>
```

The XML is in DB kept as CLOB. I need to extract the following values from the XML:

- currency
- `DenomID`
- value
- quality
- output
- ...

Comment: Which specific data do you need to extract from the XML?

Comment: hi @nop77svk, I want to extract Currency, denomID, value, quantity, output.... but this xml is kept in DB as CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to parse that XML in PL/SQL. There are built-in packages for doing exactly that. After you parse the XML, you can use the [`extract`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions051.htm) function to get data from it.

```
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
     <!DOCTYPE BPS SYSTEM "bpml.dtd">
     <BPS Created="2012-04-24 11:40:41">
         <Machine SerialNumber="" Site="" SoftwareRelease="MAP_248204031" VersionInfo="" Name="" Type="BPS200">
             <ParameterSection Number="6" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:23:01" EndTime="1970-01-01 00:00:00">
                 <HeadercardUnit HeaderCardID="1706539" DepositID="01706539" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:39:57" MilliSec="0" EndTime="2012-04-24 11:40:40" Rejects="NO">
                     <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Fit" Output="Stacked" Number="192"></Counter>
                     <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Unfit" Output="Stacked" Number="7"></Counter>
                 </HeadercardUnit>
             </ParameterSection>
         </Machine>
     </BPS>');
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/@Currency') as currency
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/@DenomID') as denomid
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/@Value') as val
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeaderCardUnit/Counter'))) p
    ) LOOP
    -- you can use values for r.currency, r.denomid, r.val
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @Pablo Santa Cruz, this is the extraction method i used. As this in every single tag, the value is attribute. how to extract?
converter       := XMLPARSER.NEWPARSER;
  XMLPARSER.PARSECLOB(converter,xml_content);
  XmlDoc          := XMLPARSER.GETDOCUMENT(converter);
  WABlockList := XMLDOM.GETELEMENTSBYTAGNAME(XmlDoc,'BPS');

Comment: i need to get this value '22550', '200', 'Fit'... from this line
<Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Fit" Output="Stacked" Number="192"></Counter>

Answer (score 0):

I don't have "bpml.dtd" file. I have deleted 2nd line.

[See more information here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb04cre.htm)

```
DECLARE
  x XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
     <BPS Created="2012-04-24 11:40:41">
         <Machine SerialNumber="" Site="" SoftwareRelease="MAP_248204031" VersionInfo="" Name="" Type="BPS200">
             <ParameterSection Number="6" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:23:01" EndTime="1970-01-01 00:00:00">
                 <HeadercardUnit HeaderCardID="1706539" DepositID="01706539" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:39:57" MilliSec="0" EndTime="2012-04-24 11:40:40" Rejects="NO">
                     <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Fit" Output="Stacked" Number="192"></Counter>
                     <Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Unfit" Output="Stacked" Number="7"></Counter>
                 </HeadercardUnit>
             </ParameterSection>
         </Machine>
     </BPS>');
BEGIN
  FOR y IN (
    SELECT Value(p).extract('/Counter/@Currency').getStringVal() as currency,
          Value(p).extract('/Counter/@DenomID').getNumberVal() as denomid,
          Value(p).extract('/Counter/@Value').getNumberVal() as val,
          Value(p).extract('/Counter/@Quality').getStringVal() as qual,
          Value(p).extract('/Counter/@Output').getStringVal() as output,
           Value(p).extract('/Counter/@Number').getNumberVal() as numb
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/Counter'))) p
    ) LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(y.currency||','||y.denomid||','|| y.val||','||y.qual||','||y.output||','|| y.numb );

    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: what is ur 'c' stand for?

FROM   TABLE(c(Extract(x,'/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/Counter'))) p
    ) LOOP

Comment: My data is kept in DB as CLOB.. This method cant work

Comment: [XMLTABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) can do when you kept your xml in DB. If you give me table structure and what error did you get, I might help.

Comment: my xml in DB is the xml i shared at the top

Comment: can i know how you remove the second line? i have solved this clob to xml problem already.

Comment: i mean this "bpml.dtd". How you remove this second line?

Comment: Use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm). ex. `Extract(XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(table.column, '<!DOCTYPE[^<]*>', '')),'/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/Counter')`

Comment: can you provide me the full code on how to use this regexp?
Thanks